# Solution for GPG expandrive key error

Tags: apt, gnupg

al intentar ejecutar sudo apt-get update en ubuntu 22, obtengo el siguiente error:

W: Error de GPG: https://packages.expandrive.com/expandrive stable InRelease: Las siguientes firmas no fueron válidas: EXPKEYSIG 0FB0547682F8C86A ExpanDrive, Inc. support@expandrive.com
E: El repositorio «https://packages.expandrive.com/expandrive stable InRelease» no está firmado.

Alguna idea sobre cómo solucionarolo?

Un saludo y gracias.